# Linear Transformation /Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $P_2(\Bbb R)$ denote the vector space of polynomials of degree less or equal $3$ with real coefficients. Let $T : \Bbb{R}^2 \to P_2(\Bbb R)$ be the map defined by $$
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix} \right)= (a+b)x^2+(a-b)x+2a+b. $$

a) Show that T is a linear transformation.

b) Show that T is one-to-one.

c) Find a basis for the range, $\operatorname{rank}(T)$.

d) Let $\beta=\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)$
and $\gamma=(x^2,1-x,2+x)$ be ordered bases of $\Bbb R^2$ and $P_2(\Bbb R)$ respectively. Compute $[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$

For a) I need to prove $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$. But there is no $y$ element in T. (and it's bugging me out)

For  b) $N(T)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}∈R^2| T\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}(a+b)x^2\\(a-b)x\\2a+b\end{bmatrix}=0\right\}$. Which leads to $a=b=0$. So T is 1-1.

For c) and d) I have no idea.Any help/solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you kindly. Did the (a) part, T is a linear transformation and I proved it. I have a question about (c).  $T(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix})=0$ which gives the equtions: $(a+b)x^2=0 ,(a-b)x=0$ and  $2a+b=0$.  And the new matrix will  be  $\begin{bmatrix}x^2&x^2\\x&-x\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$. The RREF:$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. So$\begin{bmatrix}x^2\\x\\2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}x^2\\-x\\1\end{bmatrix}$ form a  basis for the range or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

c) $P^3(R)$ and $R^4$ are isomorphic (as vector spaces) by a usual isomorphism like $G(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$. Note that $(G\circ T)\left(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{bmatrix}0\\a+b\\a-b\\2a+b\end{bmatrix}\right)$. Since $G\circ T$ is a L.T. from $R^4$ to $R^4$, a spannig set for its range is the columns of its canonical matrix. Find an echelon form for the matrix and look for the columns that have the pivots. Back to the initial matrix and take the same columns and you have a basis for the range of $G\circ T$. The vectors (polinomials) that are pre-images of the vectors of this basis will be the basis you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(a) $y$ is just a vector inside $\mathbb{R}^2$. Also, you need to show $T(\lambda x) = \lambda T(x) \forall \lambda \in  \mathbb{R}$

(b) you got

(c) just map the standard basis vectors from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and they will form a basis for the range.

(d) First find a matrix representaion of $T$ under the standard bases. You have to use a change of basis from the standard basis to $\beta$. Therefore, you will take the inverse of the basis transformation and then multiply $T$ by the inverse matrix. Lastly, you need one more transformation to go from the standard basis in $P^3(\mathbb{R})$ to the desired basis.

Comment: It is one to one, not onto. We are mapping from a lower dimensional space into a higher. I believe what you mean to say is that it can't be onto.

Comment: My solution for (a)$T{(\begin{bmatrix}x_1+y_1\\x_2+y_2\\x_3+y_3\end{bmatrix})}=\begin{bmatrix}(a+b)x^2\\(a-b)x\\2a+b\end{bmatrix}$ and T(x)+T(y)=$T{(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{bmatrix})}=\begin{bmatrix}(a+b)x_1^2+(a+b)y_1^2\\(a-b)x_2+(a-b)y_2\\2a+b\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Your inputs should be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the a and b should be the components of your input. I think the notation is confusing you.

Comment: Aren't x and y vectors in $R^2$? I'm really stuck in this (a) part. If you're not busy can you please send a solution to this?

Comment: I'm also saying the inverse matrix of the change if basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The inverse of the matrix where $(1,0)$ gets sent to  $(1,1)$ and $(0,1)$ gets sent to $(-1,1)$

Comment: They are vectors. But they have components which are corresponding to the a's and b's. A typical vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an ordered pair (a,b). When we add two vectors in this setting, we add their components. So let $y = (c,d)$ $x + y = (a +c ,b +d)$. I'm not using the column notation, but it's the same. Note that a,b,c,d are just arbitrary elements from $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I believe it is necessary. You need to have that inverse matrix because we aren't truly mapping from the canonical representation.

Comment: It does matter. The way this operator is defined is with the canonical basis. The question in terms of a new basis. So you can't just input $(a,b) = a(1,0) + b(0,1)$ because this is not a(1,1) + b(-1,1).

Comment: I still don't think you are correct. Also, you should  properly use a translator so you don't confuse the OP. I understood T to be in terms of the basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$. So we can express $T$ in terms of the the new basis in the codomain. You did that. However, you can't just look at T(1,1). Why? Because $(1,1) represents (1)(1,1) + 1(-1,1) with respect to the new basis.  So what im saying is that we transform the inputs from our new basis back to the canonical and then apply our transform.